# AVAudioPlayer not adjusting rate

Tags: ios, xcode, avaudioplayer

I have two AVAudioPlayer's in my XCode project for my iPhone app.

They are initiated as follows:

```
    self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:heliSoundURL error:nil];
    [self.audioPlayer setNumberOfLoops:-1];
    [self.audioPlayer setVolume:1.0];
    [self.audioPlayer enableRate];
    [self.audioPlayer play];
```

And somewhere along the line I call a method that calls `[self.audioPlayer setRate:.5f];` and it is doing nothing.

I have also tried changing the rate before the call to `play` and nothing works. Perhaps I need to use a certain file format?

Comment: Where your display the rating? and try to print rate like  NSLog(@"player rate %f",self.audioPlayer.rate);

Answer (score 0):

You must set enableRate to YES for the rate property to take effect and 
You must set this before calling prepareToPlay.

```
self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:heliSoundURL error:nil];

self.audioPlayer.delegate = self;

[self.audioPlayer setNumberOfLoops:-1];

[self.audioPlayer setVolume:1.0];

[self.audioPlayer setEnableRate:YES];

[self.audioPlayer setRate:.5f];

[self.audioPlayer prepareToPlay];

[self.audioPlayer play];
```

I hope this will help you.

Cheers

Comment: I tested the code and it works for me. About second line you need declare Delegate protocol.  @interface YourClassName : UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>.  Set [self.audioPlayer setEnableRate:YES]; before [self.audioPlayer setRate:.5f]; line. Then, [self.audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
[self.audioPlayer play];

Comment: I've set enableRate = true but it's still not showing any rate change for me. I'm trying with rates: 0.5, 1.25, 1.5, 2.0. It's always playing at regular rate 1.0. I'm not sure what the issue is. I tried disabling isMeteringEnabled but that didn't work either. Changing the currentTime to fastforward or rewind works however